# Python Queue.Queue.get Method

Tags: python

In the python documentation, it says

> exception Queue.Empty
>       Exception raised when non-blocking get() (or get_nowait()) is called on a Queue object which is empty.

So I wonder whether the following coding will ever raise the Queue.Empty exception because the way it use 'get' method seems non-blocking.

Here is the code.

```
try:
    request = self._requests_queue.get(True, self._poll_timeout)
except Queue.Empty:
    continue
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) says everything you need to know to answer the question (emphasis mine):

> `Queue.get([block[, timeout]])`
>
> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args `block` is `true` and `timeout` is `None` (the default), block if necessary until an item is available. **If `timeout` is a positive number, it blocks at most `timeout` seconds and raises the `Empty` exception if no item was available within that time.** Otherwise (`block` is false), return an item if one is immediately available, else raise the `Empty` exception (`timeout` is ignored in that case).